# migrating 9 tables into one BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I am trying to copy data from 8 tables into one empty table in BigQuery.
I wish to move the costs I have from first company into all_costs. I tried insert and discovered it's not being supported, will love to get some help here with me code.
all_costs is an empty table containing the following fields, same as every other table
It also need to create a new column stating the company name

```
Date    Country Operation system    Costs type  costs
Yyyy-dd-mm  At  And a   12
Yyyy-dd-mm  at  And b   324.245
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM  [Costs.all_costs] A
JOIN EACH [Costs.first_company] B 
ON (B.date < '05-06-2015') AND (A.date is NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below simple code should work for you

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT 'company_1' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_1]), 
  (SELECT 'company_2' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_2]), 
  (SELECT 'company_3' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_3]), 
  (SELECT 'company_4' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_4]), 
  (SELECT 'company_5' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_5]), 
  (SELECT 'company_6' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_6]), 
  (SELECT 'company_7' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_7]), 
  (SELECT 'company_8' AS company, * FROM  [Costs.company_8])
```

Make sure you set Destination Table and Write Preference in UI (under <kbd>Show Options</kbd> button)

Comment: Hi thanks it worked perfect! thank you, is there a way to set it to auto run?